# How to replace all '\' to '/' in nodejs

Tags: regex, node.js

I'm new to nodejs.
Can anyone tell me how to replace all '\' to '/' ? Thanks.

my code:`console.log(process.cwd());`
result:`e:\Workspace\WebStorm\Ren\LittleCase`

I have tried the following methods：

```
console.log(process.cwd().replace('\\','/'));
```

However, only the first to be successfully replaced.like this:

```
e:/Workspace\WebStorm\Ren\LittleCase
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're really close!

The problem is that Javascript doesn't match more then once. But don't worry! You can use a RegExp!

To make a regex, just replace the quotes with backslashes: `/\\/`. That will match `\`

Sadly, that will only match once, so you can add the global flag `g` to the end: `/\\/g`.

So, with your example, that would be:

```
console.log(process.cwd().replace(/\\/g,'/'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace only replaces the first instance; however, if you turn it into a regular expression with a global modifier, it will replace all instances.

```
var regex = /\\/g;
process.cwd().replace(regex, '/');
```

There are some other, but less orthodox (i.e. less readable to future programmers) methods: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17606289/703229

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a regexp to replace more than one occurence

```
.replace(/\\/g,'/')
```